# function for choosing some index in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i'm doing the exercice of one of the famous dataset classification of cellular phone by price, and this part is the part for standardization of dataset.
but i have to exclude the column of the price to have a data standardization.
how can i do? cause i'm following some tutorials but i cant understand those first two lines of code:

```
x = mdb.iloc[:, 0:15].values # le prime 16 classi
y = mdb.iloc[:, -4].values
x = StandardScaler().fit_transform(x)
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, 
                                   test_size=0.20, random_state=0)
print(f"Nr di record in training: {x_train.shape[0]}")
print(f"Nr di record in test: {x_test.shape[0]}")
```

pleas explain every syntax of the code lines in the example, cause i dont understand what does it mean. i think first [] is for choosing the column for std? but the price is the 17th column and after that i have other columns to take. if i write [:, 0:15] i take only the first 16 row? and what is the first argument of the []?

i tried to change some things but the result of my accuracy score change to 100% (and its not real).

i f every things remain the same the accuracy is 95% but some columns are excluded.

Comment: Please format your code and make sure other people can run it.

Answer (score 1):

What `mdb.iloc` does is to select a portion (segment) of your DataFrame. So the first argument of the [] is the rows you want to select (for example [0:5] would select the first 6 rows), then the second argument would select the columns the same way. So if you do `mdb.iloc[:, 0:15]` that would select ALL rows (since you're not defining limits just using :), and the first 16 columns.

To actually eliminate just the Price column, you can use `mdb.drop(columns=['name of column'])` where you can replace the name of the column for price. You can check the name of the columns by printing `mdb.columns.values`.

If you're using the kaggle dataset, I believe the column you're referring to is price_range. So you would need to do `x = mdb.drop(columns=['price_range'])` and that would save a copy of the dataframe without the price column in x.

Comment: Rodrigo thank you so much!!! now its clear!
so, i have to write x = mdb.drop(columns=['price_range']) instead mdb.iloc[:, 0:15].values?

Comment: Yes, that would be for x. Then for y it would be `y = mdb[mdb['price_range']]` to select the prince range column. Since y is for the target values. Then you use StandardSclaer to standardize the data. Then you can split it into train and testing.